# CSS3 Side Menu, move around screen?

Tags: css

I have written some CSS3 code for a side menu but I need to move the menu further down the screen (as it is to high). Which part of the css3 do I need to change in order to move the menu around? My CCS3code is below or you may view the entire webpage at http://codepen.io/aaron_1986/pen/wMYoYK

```
#navigationMenu li{
    list-style:none;
    height:39px;
    padding:2px;
    width:40px;

}
#navigationMenu span {
    width:0;
    left:38px;
    padding:0;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;

    font-family:'Myriad Pro',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing:0.6px;
    white-space:nowrap;
    line-height:39px;

    /* CSS3 Transition: */
    -webkit-transition: 0.25s;

    /* Future proofing (these do not work yet): */
    -moz-transition: 0.25s;
    transition: 0.25s;
}

#navigationMenu a{
    /* The background sprite: */
    background: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/dejafqqbm/image/upload        /v1454847965/navigation_kxrtcc.jpg') no-repeat;

   height:39px;
    width:38px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}

#navigationMenu a:hover span{ width:auto; padding:0      20px;overflow:visible;     }
#navigationMenu a:hover{
text-decoration:none;

-moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #fff;
box-shadow:0 0 5px #fff;
}

#navigationMenu .home { background-position:0 0;}
#navigationMenu .home:hover {   background-position:0 -39px;}
#navigationMenu .home span{
background-color:#7da315;
 color:#3d4f0c;
text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #99bf31;
}

#navigationMenu .images { background-position:-38px 0;}
#navigationMenu .images:hover { background-position:-38px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .images span{
   background-color:#1e8bb4;
    color:#223a44;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #44a8d0;
}

   #navigationMenu .Links { background-position:-76px 0;}
   #navigationMenu .Links:hover { background-position:-76px -39px;}
   #navigationMenu .Links span{
    background-color:#c86c1f;
    color:#5a3517;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d28344;
}

#navigationMenu .ContactUs { background-position:-114px 0;}
#navigationMenu .ContactUs:hover{ background-position:-114px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .ContactUs span{
  background-color:#d0a525;
  color:#604e18;
  text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d8b54b;
}

#navigationMenu .hhh { background-position:-38px 0;}
#navigationMenu .hhh:hover { background-position:-38px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .hhh span{
    background-color:#af1e83;
    color:#460f35;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d244a6;
}
#navigationMenu .ggg { background-position:-76px 0;}
#navigationMenu .ggg:hover { background-position:-76px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .ggg span{
    background-color:#ffb1b1;
    color:#5a3517;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d28344;
}

#navigationMenu .zzz { background-position:-114px 0;}
#navigationMenu .zzz:hover{ background-position:-114px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .zzz span{
    background-color:#d9d1ff;
    color:#604e18;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d8b54b;
}
```

Comment: Your margin top is `#navigationMenu` `margin-top: 16.50%;` which tells that it should be `16.50%` of parent height. You can adjust it to your desired  output.

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, all you need to do is to push down the `ul` element as much as you like in `CSS`, like this:

```
#navigationMenu {
   margin-top: 100px;
}
```

In this example, I pushed it down for `100px` but you can have some percentage value as well. Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/ZQqdrR)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```css
#navigationMenu {
  margin-top: 4.50%;
}
```

cekout: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWQNNg

Answer (score 0):

you can use

**#navigationMenu 
{
  margin-top: 4.50%;
}**`enter code here`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  font: 14px/20px Arial, San-Serif;
  color: #555;
  margin: 0;
}

#navigationMenu li{
 list-style:none;
 height:39px;
 padding:2px;
 width:40px;
  
}
#navigationMenu span {
 width:0;
 left:38px;
 padding:0;
 position:absolute;
 overflow:hidden;

 font-family:'Myriad Pro',Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:18px;
 font-weight:bold;
 letter-spacing:0.6px;
 white-space:nowrap;
 line-height:39px;

 /* CSS3 Transition: */
 -webkit-transition: 0.25s;

 /* Future proofing (these do not work yet): */
 -moz-transition: 0.25s;
 transition: 0.25s;
}

#navigationMenu a{
 /* The background sprite: */
 background: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/dejafqqbm/image/upload/v1454881544/tits_cv39ed.jpg') no-repeat;

 height:39px;
 width:38px;
 display:block;
 position:relative;
}

#navigationMenu a:hover span{ width:auto; padding:0 20px;overflow:visible; }
#navigationMenu a:hover{
 text-decoration:none;

 -moz-box-shadow:0 0 5px #fff;
 -webkit-box-shadow:0 0 5px #fff;
 box-shadow:0 0 5px #fff;
}

#navigationMenu .home { background-position:0 0;}
#navigationMenu .home:hover { background-position:0 -39px;}
#navigationMenu .home span{
 background-color:#7da315;
 color:#3d4f0c;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #99bf31;
}

#navigationMenu .images { background-position: -38px 0;}
#navigationMenu .images:hover { background-position:-38px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .images span{
 background-color:#1e8bb4;
 color:#223a44;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #44a8d0;
}

#navigationMenu .Links { background-position:-76px 0;}
#navigationMenu .Links:hover { background-position:-76px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .Links span{
 background-color:#c86c1f;
 color:#5a3517;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d28344;
}

#navigationMenu .ContactUs { background-position:-114px 0;}
#navigationMenu .ContactUs:hover{ background-position:-114px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .ContactUs span{
 background-color:#d0a525;
 color:#604e18;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d8b54b;
}

#navigationMenu .hhh { background-position:-152px 0;}
#navigationMenu .hhh:hover { background-position:-152px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .hhh span{
 background-color:#af1e83;
 color:#460f35;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d244a6;
}
#navigationMenu .ggg { background-position:-190px 0;}
#navigationMenu .ggg:hover { background-position:-190px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .ggg span{
 background-color:#ffb1b1;
 color:#5a3517;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d28344;
}

#navigationMenu .zzz { background-position:-227px 0;}
#navigationMenu .zzz:hover{ background-position:-227px -39px;}
#navigationMenu .zzz span{
 background-color:#c3bce5;
 color:#604e18;
 text-shadow:1px 1px 0 #d8b54b;
}


header {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 86px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  opacity: 0.9%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

#logo {
  margin: 20px;
  float: right;
  width: 200px;
  height:55px;
  background: url(http://res.cloudinary.com/dejafqqbm/image/upload/v1454696003/logo_he9bmd.jpg) no-repeat center;
}
#navigationMenu {
  margin-top: 4.50%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UFT-8">
    <title>Web Site Images</title>
  </style>
  </head>
<body>
  <header>
    
    <a href="#" id="logo"></a>
  <ul id="navigationMenu">
    <li>
     <a class="home" href="#">
            <span>Home</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
     <a class="images" href="#">
            <span>Images</span>
        </a>
    </li>

    <li>
      <a class="Links" href="#">
            <span>Links</span>
         </a>
    </li>

    <li>
     <a class="ContactUs" href="#">
            <span>Contact Us</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    
    <li>
     <a class="hhh" href="#">
            <span>hhh</span>
        </a>
    </li>
     <li>
     <a class="ggg" href="#">
            <span>ggg</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
     <a class="zzz" href="#">
            <span>zzz</span>
        </a>
    </li>
    
 </ul>
    </u>
    </header>
```

cekout: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jWQNNg

Comment: I have used the code below - thank-you!                                    #navigationMenu {
  margin-top: 4.50%;
}